# creating different types of projects using eclipse with maven

Tags: maven

I know creating the project using maven with command prompt but if i want to import this project into eclipse i have to run some commands and it will be modified suitable for eclipse, My question is can I create different archetype projects using maven plug in to eclipse, without using maven with cmd ?

Answer (score 3):

You can entirely use Eclipse without using the command prompt. Though I prefer to use both terminal and Eclipse interfaces to utilize the maven project, and is a dynamic way of development. Eclipse Mars already include Maven.

Two ways to do this:

1. Create a new general project, create new POM file, define dependency and build, and Eclipse will recognize to configure as Maven project without applying Eclipse Project facets.
2. Create a new Maven project, do not skip archetype selection and use quickstart only if creating a simple Java project with main and test source folders, define module properties (group, artifact, version, etc.), and Eclipse will configure project as Maven project without applying Eclipse Project facets.

To execute a clean install, you need to create a goal "clean install" in Eclipse Run Configuration under Maven. Caution, Eclipse use embedded Maven runtime by default so if you'd like to link with your copy of Maven, you'll need to configure Eclipse to point at your Maven installation directory.

Basically, every command you entered in command prompt need to be a goal in Eclipse Maven Run Configuration to separate yourself from using command prompt.

Example Java Maven Project:

### Step 1: Create New Maven Project

The first step to begin Maven-enabled Java development without using command prompt.
[image: new maven project]

### Step 2: Eclipse Project Configuration

Most of the time, I usually skip this section unless special circumstance requires a working set.
[image: eclipse projet configuration]

### Step 3: Specifying Archetype

Maven archetype quickstart comes with two source package: test and main. This is the most simplest and efficient option to begin Java development. This is equivalent to *-DArchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart* option.
[image: specify archetype]

### Step 4: Define Archetype Parameters

Define your own archetype parameters.
[image: Archetype parameters]

### Step 5: Confirm Eclipse generated a Maven-enabled Java project

Double check POM and ensure Eclipse throws no error. In this case, Eclipse warns of Java 1.5 not defined. You can fix this by specifying Java version in maven-compiler-plugin within build tag in POM but that's entirely another thread.
[image: Eclipse generated Maven-enabled Java project]

### Step 6: Define a Maven Goal

We want to test whether Eclipse can do a "mvn clean install" by creating a new run configuration. You can see the console output in background that Eclipse successfully output Maven build.
[image: a maven goal]

Is this what you were asking about?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.but how to specify the archetype(Project Structure that means -DarchetypeArtifactId) in POM.xml file to update it.

Comment: Please can any one help me on this ?